# Swift - implementing NSXMLParserDelegate

Tags: swift

I'm trying to have a class of mine implement NSXmlProtocolDelegate but the compiler fails indicating that the class does not conform to NSObjectProtocol.

Is it required that all of the functions from NSObjectProtocol be implemented, or can that be avoided?

```
class GeoRssParser : NSXMLParserDelegate
{
    func parserDidStartDocument(parser : NSXMLParser)
    {

    }
}
```

Not much to see at this point - I got this far before the compiler started failing.

Comment: where is your code? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, at least anything that isn't tagged as @optional. The easiest way to achieve this would be to simply make your class a subclass of NSObject, which already conforms to the NSObjectProtocol, and implements all its methods.

```
class GeoRssParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    func parserDidStartDocument(parser : NSXMLParser) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize that you needed to inherit from NSObject explicitly.

Comment: @Lee Well, you don't necessarily have to, you could directly just specify that your class conforms to NSObjectProtocol, but then you'd have to implement all of the methods your self. This way just saves you all the work.

Comment: Is this because the definition of the NSXMLParserDelegate looks like this?protocol NSXMLParserDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

Comment: @Lee That is correct. If one protocol conforms to another, the method implementation requirements get passed down.